# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable for a FOR loop

Tags: python, anaconda, typeerror

```
for abcd in range(3):
    print("d")
```

is giving me the error `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Restart Kernal resolves the issue or if I run the code on another ipynb file I am not getting the error. I can reproduce the error multiple times. Any help to fix this without restarting the kernal ??

thanks
jaideep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing this simply code on my own raises no error and gives the expected output, so I would bet my money you have defined a variable called `range` somewhere in your code, thus renaming the `range keyword`. Then, when you call `range(3)` so get an error because you are not actually calling the python range function, but your own `str` variable.